# Using flow types on a dynamically built object

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm starting to use flow type checker on my javascript code. I tend to be quite functional using javascript and I often build APIs dinamically.

For example, this is quite common on my code:

```
  const levels = [`error`, `warn`, `log`, `info`, `debug`];
  const API = Object.create(null);
  API.flush = flush.bind(API, false);
  // Here I'm attaching the rest of the methods to the api
  levels.reduce(
        (api, name, lvl) => {
          api[name] = handleLogMessage.bind(api, name, lvl);
          return api;
        }, API);
```

Now if I want to cover this interface with Flow I try to do something like this:

```
type iTracer = {
    flush(): void,
    warn(): void
};
```

But I get several errors, like this one: ´Property not found in possibly null value null´ or weirder: `Covariant property`warn`incompatible with contravariant use in assignment of computed property/element`

Isn't flow supposed to understand the dynamic nature of javascript and flow with it? To be honest, it is dramatically reducing my productivity, instead of boosting it.

Any help with this will be much appreciated

Comment: I've no time to put an answer together, but does this help? https://flowtype.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMANiAzgCwBQEpEDeAvgFCiSwKKYCGYAJigKYAycA5gLJPro3tNszAG5MUALkTooAJxhh2AGkQBbHnwGTpchfgIlEiCAnRxmAOhQdsa3vya4A3CVLGw0xCLHpEAXkQA2gDkTDIycDJBykEA7jQyYFGIQVbsSUHywHDp9EwARiBpALrObh4AggAKAJJ+hIhEzlXV5qgYmHVtWOZ58vTYzcrANCjoDs5eo+YyTPQgEILYNAAOMMqT+L4AfIQGiCswAZNFdbQMzGxc6vY9fUur60yiKE57M1AgCfurzkTKza8SM1zJk4Nggllsq9gXEEtgACwAJicQA